# Visual Studio 2013 publish prerequisites dialog is missing .NET Framework 4.8

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I've installed the "developer pack" (.NET Framework 4.8 SDK offline installer and my native language pack) from: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net48

I've updated my VS 2013 to update 5.

For my C# projects, in 'project properties / publish / Prerequisites' dialog, I found that I couldn't set a prerequisite of .NET Framework 4.8 because the .NET Framework 4.8 is not listed in the list box at all.
But .NET Framework 4, 4 Client Profile, 4.5, 4.5.1 as well as 4.5.2 are all there.

Anyone know where/how to get the appropriate prerequisite package from?

Answer (score 0):

I found this post: https://superuser.com/questions/1427728/visual-studio-2019-publish-prerequisites-dialog-is-missing-net-framework-4-8/1439031

But instead of using that trick which is to pretend VS 2015 is installed, I found an easier solution.

I found the value of 'Path' key in registry 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\GenericBootstrapper\12.0' is C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper.

And there is a DotNetFX48 sub-folder in my 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages'. So, I copy this sub-folder into the folder 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\Bootstrapper**Packages**'

Now the .NET Framework 4.8 appears in the list box of prerequisites dialog and I can check and select it for my VS 2013 projects.

Share the issue and solution with you all. Have a good weekend to you all.